# Set Background Color of a List Item if it is Clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, listitem

I want to change the background color of the List Item depending on whether the item is clicked or not. How can I achieve this! I did tried the following:

```
    articleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // Find the current article that was clicked on
            Article currentArticle = mAdapter.getItem(position);

            if (currentArticle.getUrl() != null) {
                TextView article_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_title);

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                {
                    article_TV.setBackgroundColor(getApplicationContext().getColor(R.color.colorItemClicked));
                }
        else
                                   article_TV.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorItemClicked));
                 }

        }
    });
```

Update :- 
Silly mistake it was. As suggested by ak sacha should be 
TextView article_TV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);

Comment: do like this.." TextView article_TV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);"

Comment: It did solve! Silly mistake!

Comment: you did as i am said?

Comment: Yes I did that only

Comment: post the answer on your own and close the open question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by ak sacha we can achieve it simply by using 
TextView article_TV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
This is because we are using that in a adapter, so we need to find the view within listview row.Hence we use view.findviewbyid